# Selenium Python crashes because of to less sleep

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a script with multiple lines for selenium webscraping in python. Sometimes the websites take time to load longer which results into a crash of the script.

Therefore my question is, is there any other solution apart from using sleep? Or can I repeat somehow line by line with try and except until it works?

Thx

Comment: set implicity_wait, i use a "proxy" function that will call "get_element" selenium function with some protections

Comment: @Wonka Thx implicity_wait will work similar to the sleep function and it still does not wait automatically until the page is loaded, what leads to a crash as well or do I miss somthing?

Comment: Can you show how did you implemented it? 1) code section how you init driver and settings used. 2) extraction code. Just post relevant code